# How to add css styles to table with ajax loaded data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table where data is loaded through ajax.
The columns are as follows:

Name | Email | Delivery_date

Now I am ordering the data by delivery date. So I want to color those rows who have same delivery date so that rows with same delivery date can be distinguished.

ps- I am using datatables server side processing to load data dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with [row created callback](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html), all that you need is to build your function `dateToOddOrEvenCssClass` which will convert date to css class (let say we will have only two options for odd and even dates):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            $('td', row).eq(2).addClass( dateToOddOrEvenCssClass( data[2] ) ); //.eq(2) and data[2], 2 stands for Delivery_date column
        }
    } );
} );
```

**Update 1.**

If odd or even solution isn't suitable for you can implement whatever you want (I suggested odd or even because you didn't provided details about coloring logic), but you generate color from date and add that color as a style for your cell like so:

```
$('td', row).eq(2).css( 'background-color', dateToColor( data[2] ) );
```

Only need to implement `dateToColor` function.

Comment: Although your solution is good but the problem here is if two consecutive dates are even then they both will be applied the same class.

Comment: @sameershaikh you mentioned that you "ordering the data by delivery date" which means that unlikely you will get two odd/even consecutive dates (unless you have some dates missing). But you can do with **$('td', row).eq(2)** whatever you want - it represents your date column.

Comment: Although your solution worked but i want only two set of colors. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for this:

```
$("td:contains('<specific_date>')").parent().css({'background':'blue'})
```

Comment: The problem is i have hundred's of date